# Download error by mediatap application

Tags: ios

I got a massage while I was downloading a video from face book . Which is about an error due to violation of the limit of 
API calls.
Please let me know what’s that mean.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error trying to download my own YouTube videos to my iPhone